# FullCalendar no renderiza (Angular)

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

estoy realizando lo siguiente:

En angular genere un componente navBar y un componente de calendario (Este ultimo utiliza FullCalendar), seguidamente dentro del navBar cargo el componente de Calendario pero este no se visualiza bien, al utilizar las herramientas de desarrollo cambio de vista a dispositivos y se visualiza bien pero de primera entrada no se me ve bien y no comprendo por que.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este otra imagen al ver en pantalla de dispositivos se visualiza bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Antes que te cierren la pregunta y/o te den negativos, lectura altamente sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 y antes que te enojes y/o incomodes por el contenido de dicho enlace, considera que las preguntas bien estructuradas tienen mayor chance de obtener respuesta. Por cierto, bienvenido/a a SOes, esto te ayudará a entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y aquí las recomendaciones para preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Saludos.

Comment: Hola chicos/as agradezco sus recomendaciones, voy a tratar de detallar mas la pregunta, estuve investigando un poco y al parecer full calendar tiene algun tipo de conflicto con la la directiva ng-template de angular, aun no lo he logrado solucionar, gracias de antemano.